# Is handling http calls from multiple intent services good approach?

Tags: android, rest, design-patterns, structure, intentservice

I'm developing restful android application, but I'm still newbie to android, and I would like to avoid beginners bed structural design that would  cost me troubles latter.

I've read lots of discussions about android services and restful applications, many of them contrary to each other, so I would like to know have I choosen a good approach.

Inspired by this presentation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE I put my http requests into IntentServices, instead of the Async Task.

I've choose Intent Service because of:

- as a services they are not sensitive to foreground/background switching like Activities (won't get killed).
- Intent service provides work in separate thread, so the user interface stays responsive.

Since Intent Service cannot run multiple request simultaneously, I've "split" my domain  into few groups and for each group I have written my Intent Service. (ends up in: one CRUD set -> one intent service)
This way I got that inside of a group can be only one request running at a time (And this is good for me, since this way it could never be executed for example update and delete at same unit).
And, on the other side, I can run multiple requests at the same time if they are from the other groups, and don't affect each other.

So basically, I have this:

- one generic HTTPRequest class that builds requests from name value pairs
- UserIntentService - creates user related requests and executes it by using HTTPRequest cass, and proccess request using UserProcessor. Notifies caller by intent with data.
- CallIntentService - creates call related requests and executes it by using HTTPRequest cass 
  and proccess request using CallProcessor. Notifies caller by intent with data.
- UserProcessor - parsing response
- CallProcessor - parsing response
- ServiceHelper - finds and starts right intent service

When using from activity, I use something like this: SeviceHelper.StartService (action, data), 
and I get response by local BroadcastReceiver inside of the activity. I register receiver on the OnStart(), and unregister it on the onStop() method of the activity.

Is that a good approach?

Should I have only one IntentService for all calls? 
Is it better to have   one Service that runs all the time in background, instead of using Intent Service that has to be started for each request?

Is there any other things that can get bad with this approach that I'm missing?